# No errors: Blank page on my React App after running create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reducer, { initialState } from "./reducer";
import { StateProvider } from "./StateProvider";

//const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
      <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVHgD.png)

When I press control+ Shift+ J I see no errors. I see no error even on reloading the page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yftfb.png)

I even tried older versions of ReactDOM hence the comment

Comment: Please show app component and if possible add stackblitz or codesandbox link